# How to cache pickle load to avoid re loading every run?

Tags: python, caching, pickle

I have a very large pickle file on which I am running some analysis.

Loading it takes up to a minute, and I do it hundreds of times a day.

Is there a way to keep the file contents in memory and avoid re-loading?

Limitations:

- I don't want to use notebooks
- I want to be able to change my main script, and not run in a console
- I am using Pycharm

Thanks

Comment: you can maybe pickle to a ramdisk

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I would also like to know

Comment: @JulesG.M. Only thing I can think of is a service that runs in the background and serves chunks of the file via an API.

Comment: @JulesG.M. got an answer

Comment: shelve saves onto disk so I don't see why that's better

Comment: unless the fact that it's chunked makes it better for you

Comment: My solution is to use HDF5 with h5py, which is much faster than pickle and np.save if the object has a lot of numerical stuff in it

Comment: @JulesG.M. Maybe you can post an extra answer?

Answer (score 0):

Can you not keep the unpickled object directory in-memory and re-use it?

```
import pickle

_CACHED_OBJ = None

def load_object(pickled_value):
    global _CACHED_OBJ
    _CACHED_OBJ = pickle.loads(pickled_value)


def run_your_code():
    # You can use _CACHED_OBJ which is already loaded
    pass


def init():
    load_object(pickled_value)
```

P.S: I'm not sure how your code is run. If you are running a script, of course the runtime will be short lived and this wouldn't work. If you are running a web server or something on those lines like a long running process and need to access the pickle multiple times, this'd be a potential solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found the [shelve](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html) built in module.

This allows to split the file into chunks which are saved on disk according to some key, then load them when needed.

```
import shelve


with shelve.open('my_db') as db:
    db['eggs'] = 'eggs'
```

The underlying serialization uses pickle.

This is not thread safe.

Comment: this isn't in memory right..

Comment: @JulesG.M. it isn't but it is next best, when compared to ease of use. The use case wanted to avoid a big load time at the start, which this does achieve.